# Making UIView foreground transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I am modifying an IOS app to allow an additional background layer. All the existing overlays are `UIImageViews`, which handle `transparency` just fine.

The existing background is the main `UIView`. I want to change the black background to `transparent`, to put another view behind. It doesn't work. The simplest code which doesn't work as I would hope is as follows:

```
# import "TestUIView.h"
@implementation TestUIView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.opaque = NO;
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0,0,0,0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
// and here goes my code where I draw to the transparent background
}
@end
```

When this is executed, it produces a black rectangle. I have set its background to transparent and filled its foreground with transparent. What do I have to do to get a `UIView` where I can draw against a transparent background?

(And I know I can change the `alpha` of the view as a whole, that's not the issue. I want opaque drawing on a truly transparent background).

UPDATE: Its not in the setbackgroundcolor, I appreciate it isn't necessary and so shouldn't be there, but the same thing happens if it is commented out. I can't draw against a transparent background; the code above shows I can't even make a transparent rectangle to draw onto.

Thanks

Comment: just try
yourview.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithComponent:0.5];

Comment: if alpha is 0, you will see nothing. What do you expect then?

Comment: by default opaue is NO.

Answer (score 4):

By default the value of `opaque` is `NO`. Also if you set the alpha to 0, then the view will be completely invisible to the user.If you want to have transparency, then you need to have an alpha value greater than 0 and less than 1.

Also the `backgroundColor` property is used to set the view’s color rather than drawing that color yourself.

If you need to change the background color in `drawRect`, you will have to draw it yourself:

```
self.backgroundColor=yourColorWithSomeAlphaValue;//
[self.backgroundColor setFill];
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
```

More explanation is provided in [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873663/why-cant-you-change-a-uiview-background-color-in-drawrect)

Comment: Searching for the same and this is exactly what I am looking for. thanks Mr.T

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens if I comment out my setBackgroundColor. In that case I am just drawing a transparent rectangle, except its not transparent, its black (there is a UIView underneath it which is obscured).

Comment: sry i didnt get u, what happened ?

Comment: Please don't use `code blocks` for emphasis, only for code.